# LibGDX, TextButton in Stage doesn't get inputs all the time

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx, stage

I have a HudStage class (extending the LibGDX Stage class) in which I'm drawing a Table filled with current game information like positions, health points etc.

As I also want to have a TextButton in this Table, I implemented the following code:

```
public class HUDStage extends Stage{
    public HudStage() {
        ...
        Table table = new Table();
        ...

        final TextButton button = new TextButton("buttontext", skin);
        button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                System.out.println("buttonchecked: " + button.isChecked());
            }
        });
        table.add(button).left();
        ...
        clear();
        this.addActor(table);
    }
    ...
}
```

which works fine, as long as I call the code in that constructor only one time. I can click the button and the correct line is being printed.

Because the information to be drawn is getting updated every single render()-call in my main lifecycle, I also have to create the Table again every time. I put the EXACT same Table-code from the constructor into a new method and call it every render()-call manually.

Now the updated data is being showed the way I want it and the TextButton is still visible.
But all of the sudden I can't click it anymore ...

After researching why I'm not able to get the TextButton to work properly, I ensured the InputProcessor and the size of the button is set correctly (shouldn't make a difference anyway, as it already worked properly with one single call). Also, the table is the only Actor in this HudStage.
I furthermore tested to put the TextButton into a global variable and therefore used the same TextButton with the same ChangeListener every time, I just can't get it to work and would be glad if someone could help me out on this one ...

Comment: Ok, as I understand, I cant .clear() the Stage right there, because if I click the button on the screen to get the changed()-method from the ChangeListener to execute, it triggers an 'old' version, not the one I add right after the .clear() ... I figured it out by simply not clearing the actors of the stage: when I clicked i got 'clicked actor 12 of 15' for example

Comment: But isn't there a way, to clear the table completely and 'build' it new again with different data ?! How am I supposed to update the information in the table, if the Listener stops working when I clear the 'old' data?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling new in the render thread under any circumstances really. Why are you creating a new Table every time you need to draw something? Instantiate the table once, lay it out, add the listeners, and call Table.draw() in your render() method.